# Java bits to Integer

Tags: java, byte, bit

I have an application that is sending me 2 shorts one increments from 0 -> 32 -> 48 -> 16 then back to 0 and the second increments each time the first one hits 0. The second one goes up to a maximum of 65535 and then loops round back to 0. I'm guessing this is some bits that are encoded which can be made to create a single number?

How can I combine these two shorts into a single number that increments by 1 if they increment in the behaviour described above?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
0b0000_0000  0
0b0010_0000 32
0b0011_0000 48
0b0001_0000 16
```

So you can increment a counter modulo 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, ... and switch the two bits. Modulo 4 means `& 0b11`.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    System.out.printf("%04x%n", x);
    x = (x + 1) & 0xFFFF;
    x |= (x & 2) << 16;
    x |= ~((x & 2) ^ (x & 1)) << 17; // Or something like that
}
```

I leave it to you to find the logic.